# how to make a web part themable in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, css, theme

I have a SharePoint add-in and some custom web parts. The problem is that I want these web parts to be themable.. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create few style sheets(css) files for the webparts and swap them using some controls like dropdown or choice buttons.

you can write a javascript code to create these controls and use this code inside content editor webpart besides your custom webpart

[Reference](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Change-Style-Sheet-Using-Tutorial-CSS-Swap-Stylesheet)

Comment: I cannot make a css file for every theme in SharePoint out there. Thanks for your reply anyways.